# Python 3.X reading null values from a table

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pycharm

let's assume that I have a resultset with a couple of fields. Now one of these fields is coming as 'NULL' or in Python language None. Now I need to create a method to replace whole Nones in a field by a specific word example 'UNKNOWN'. Here is my method.

```
def definegender(x):
    if x is not None:
      return x
    else:
        x = 'unknown'
        return x
```

Now testing

```
z= None
definegender(z)
print('{}'.format(z))
```

Unfortunately, my approach does not work, please can you guys let me know the best way to create this validation. Thanks

Comment: You cannot assign by reference in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you aim to do is assign by reference. Is some languages like C, C++ and C# that is possible. In Java and Python it is not. You can alter the state (if you for instance pass a list, you can update the elements, but you cannot set another list to it).

You can however use an **assignment operator**:

```
z = None
z = definegender(z)
print('{}'.format(z))
```

Furthermore you can make the code shorter by using a ternary operator in the `definegender` function:

```
def definegender(x):
    return x if x is not None else 'unknown'
```

Comment: Hi buddy, when I try  z = definegender(z) without a previous named i got this error NameError: name 'z' is not defined

Comment: @AndresAngel: of course you first have to make sure that `z` is initialized, like in your own code fragment.

Comment: Well i initialized as z= None but it didnt return 'unknown' :(

Comment: @AndresAngel: If I run it on my machine, `z` is `'undefined'` after the call. Are you sure you set `z` to `None` and not to the string `'None'`?

Comment: Awesome works like that!! z= None
print(definegender(z))